# Read content of binary file as unsigned long, update and save in another binary file

Tags: c, file-io, type-conversion, endianness

I want to read a binary file, operate a 64 bit encryption logic and save the returned file in a binary file. Since the encryption operates on 2 blocks of 4 bytes of integer I read the file twice and do conversion to long int. But when I tried to decrypt using the same process, I saw that what I saved from the encryption output was wrong. Here is my code so far.

```
     while (fread(buffer, 1, 4, src) == 4) {
    //convert char to long
    message_left = buffer[3] | (unsigned long) (buffer[2] << 8) | (unsigned long) (buffer[1] << 16) | (unsigned long)(buffer[0] << 24);
    fread(buffer, 1, 4, src);
    //convert char to long
    message_right = buffer[3] | (unsigned long) (buffer[2] << 8) | (unsigned long) (buffer[1] << 16) | (unsigned long)(buffer[0] << 24);
    //encrypt
    Encrypt(ctx,&message_left,&message_right);
    //convert back to char and save
    buffer[3] = (unsigned char)message_left;
    buffer[2] = (unsigned char)(message_left >>  8);
    buffer[1] = (unsigned char)(message_left >> 16);
    buffer[0] = (unsigned char)(message_left >> 24);
    fwrite(buffer,4,1,dest);
    buffer[3] = message_rigt;
    buffer[2] = (unsigned char)(message_right >>  8);
    buffer[1] = (unsigned char)(message_right >> 16);
    buffer[0] = (unsigned char)(message_right >> 24);
    fwrite(buffer,4,1,dest);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what the problem seems to be?

Comment: When I try to reconstruct the data, by reading 4 bytes two times and apply "convert char to long" message_left and Message_right are not equal to the original values before the write.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
unsigned long n[2];
while (fread(n, sizeof(n), 1, src) == 1) {
    Encrypt(ctx, &n[0], &n[1]);
    fwrite(n, sizeof(n), 1, dest);
}
```